# Provide custom dns resolver address in a tool to download files

Tags: curl, wget

I am building a docker image that doesn't have `sudo` or permission to modify `/etc/resolv.conf`.
The requirement is to be able to download from an internal artifactory, and to resolve the DNS address which has a dynamic IP. There's a DNS server provided to be able to resolve the address.
I read that curl built with c-ares enabled has the option to provide custom DNS resolver. Is there a better practice to work with such a use-case? Any other tools?

Comment: I dont get it. If your FQDN resolve to a dynamic IP, just use the FQDN...

Comment: @Marc The FQDN is under a corporate VPN resolvable by corporate's custom resolver. The docker container will need to know how to resolve that FQDN. I do not want to copy the whole /etc/resolv.conf from the host filesystem, I need just 1 address. Also, in later docker versions, /etc/resolv.conf is read-only. I don't want to use `sudo` for security reasons.